# Match Strings between two lists

Tags: r, string

I have two lists, a list of Customers, and a second list of Customers with their Customer number. I'd like to match on the Customer names and return their Customer number.

What are the best ways to match the Customer strings between the two lists ?.

Note the names may not match exactly, so 'Company Name Inc' / 'Company Incorporated' / 'Company-Name Inc' / 'COMPANYNAME Inc' ...

Are there any commands which will provide the best match ?

Thanks
Gavin

Comment: I'm looking for an inexact string match, so: List 1 = Apple Ltd, PearLtd, Banana Co Ltd List 2 = Pear Limited 10001; Banana Ltd 10002; Appl Ltd 10003        List one is 3,000 items, and List 2 3 Million.

Answer (score 1):

For matching strings that aren't exactly the same, I'll point you to the `stringdist{}` package. In particular, the `amatch` function from that package should be helpful. Here's a link to the documentation:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/stringdist.pdf

Some code that would reproduce a small version of your dataframe would be useful, but I've created this short bit of code. It first creates two strings based on a few names you listed. Then I created two dataframes from that.

```
install.packages("stringdist")
library(stringdist)

names_1 <- c("Apple Ltd", "PearLtd", "Banana Co Ltd")
names_2 <- c("Pear Limited", "Banana ltd", "Appl Ltd")
cust_num <- c(10001, 10002, 10003)
df_1 <- data.frame(names_1)
df_2 <- data.frame(names_2, cust_num)

best_match <- na.omit(amatch(df_2$names_2, df_1$names_1, maxDist = 4))

df_2$cust_num[best_match]
```

The last line simply outputs a vector of the customer IDs for company names that were found in both lists.

The documentation will explain the parameters for `amatch`, but you'll run into problems with `maxDist`- set it too low, and your company names won't match. Set it too high, and you'll get false positives. You can see that happening in this example, where only two ID's will be returned, as "Pear Limited" is too far from "PearLtd".

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty deep and complicated subject.  In addition to Matt Sandgren's answer, you may want to also look at the `adist` function which is built in to R and gives Levenshtein distance IIRC.  If you're new to string matching stuff, you may want to try a few more things:

- Lowercase everything you can
- Remove punctuation
- Remove words that you know are useless (Inc, Incorporation, LLC, LTD, etc)
- Try weighting the terms (e.g. if you have 30% of businesses with the word 'grill' in the name, it's probably a less juicy term to match on as opposed to 'tequileria' which occurs in .01%), and look into "cosine similarity" (a very thorough treatment can be found here: http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/dot-products-1.html)

If you just want to rank some matches, that's one thing, but if false negatives/positives are an issue then that's a whole other issue!  Depends on the problem...